# Please advise an optimal solution to full text search in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, lucene.net

The documents in my database have names and descriptions among other fields. I would like to allow the users to search for those documents by providing some keywords. The keywords should be used to lookup in both the name and the description field. I've read the [mongoDB documentation on full text search](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo) and it looks really nice and easy if I want to search for keywords in the name field of my documents. However, the description field contains free form text and can take up to 2000 characters, so potentially there are a few hundred words per document. I could treat them the same way as names and just split the whole description into separate words and store it as another tag-like array (as per the Mongo example), but it seems like a terrible idea - each document's size could be almost doubled, plus there are characters like dots, commas, etc.

I know there are specialized solutions for exactly this kind of problems and I was just looking at Lucene.Net, I also saw Solr mentioned here and there.

Should I be looking to implement this search feature in mongoDB or should I use a specialized solution? Currently I just have one instance of mongod and one instance of a web server. We might need to scale later, but for now that is all I use. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to implement this feature.

Comment: I am considering MongoDB for a new project due to simplicity and need for rapid development.  I am currently looking at Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com which would provide a means to pull Document IDs, which one then uses to pull result documents from MongoDB.  I think this sets up a smooth path if MongoDB adds full text search in future.  Anyone else have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storing the text split out into an array per the documented approach is not viable (I can understand your concerns), then I think you should look into a specialised solution.

Quote from the MongoDB documentation:

> MongoDB has interesting functionality
>   that makes certain search functions
>   easy. That said, it is not a dedicated
>   full text search engine.

So, for more advanced full text search functionality I think a dedicated engine would be more suited. I have no experience in this area so I can't offer much in the way of suggestions from here, other than what my thoughts would be if I was in the same boat:

- how much work involved in using a dedicated full-text search engine instead of MongoDB's functionality?
- does that add more complexity / is it worth it?
- would it be quicker/simpler to use MongoDB and just take the hit on the extra disk space?
- maybe MongoDB will support better full-text functionality in future (it is rapidly evolving after all)

Comment: Fulltext search support is planned for thw future. However right now you have to go with Solr & friends. Using the build-in "fulltext" functionaly is not really suitable for real world usage.

Comment: I've started integrating [elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org/) for the fulltext search part. And also discovered that there's a great feature overlap between the two. :) Mongo is mature, though and I'll stick with it, but I imagine one could use ES on its own. Looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Fulltext search support is planned for the future. However right now you have to go with Solr & friends. Using the built-in "fulltext" functionality is not really suitable for real world usage.